# Class library to utilize invoking namespace

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to understand reflection in more detail.  The project I'm working on is intended to be an internal package, consumed by multiple developers.  The problem, we parse a lot of data from varying departments.  With documents that have varying headers, ordering, and often abbreviations of the name within the header.

```
Example: (Delimited Example)
Department A : 
                Date,          Volume, Depth,     Turbidity
                Date and Time, Volume, Turbidity, Depth
                Date,          Vol.,   Turb.,     Dep.
                Date,          NTU,    Vol,       Dep ft

Department B:
                Date/Time,     Flow,   Level,     Velocity
                Timestamp,     Lvl,    Flow,      Vel.
```

So in the library I wanted to include a mapping file, with a method that in essence would be called `GetHeaderConfigurations`.  Whomever references this library would be able to call the library with a user friendly name, but would pass an object with certain information.

The important piece would be their object and a namespace.  Which I would recurse the namespace for classes, ones that are details about the header within the file.

The problem:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetHeaderConfiguration(FileConfiguration configuration)
{
     var assembly = Assembly.Load(configuration.HeadersNamespace);
     // Some more code
}
```

When I call that from another application that references the library, I don't receive all of the classes.  The application builds the object, then stores the namespace in the following manner `"Sample.Headers.LabConfiguration"`.  I execute the following:

```
var headers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                       .GetTypes()
                       .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Sample.Headers");
```

The above does return all the classes within the directory in the solution, but for some odd reason when I attempt to load the assembly  the code fails.

I believe the issue is when I call `Assembly.Load` I'm passing a namespace, not an assembly.  Which leads me to the root of the question I'm hoping to understand.  How can I successfully use that namespace? How can I load the internal properties?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding what you are attempting to do, so I apologize if this suggestion is off base, but would it be possible to just use an interface and each library that needs to call your library with this `HeadersNamespace` just implements some `IProvideHeadersNamespace` interface and then you can avoid reflection all together.

Comment: you cannot load a namespace. You can only load assemblies. The classic thing to do is to load all the assemblies in a given directory or set of directoies and inspect them for the code you want (names, types etc), like you did with the GetExecutingAsembly snippet, but that only does one assemly

Comment: @pstrjds That notion is interesting, so they would pass an implementation of the inherited interface that exists within my library?

Comment: Why do you need to make your lists of headers in advance of use? But it's not clear to me what you're using them for, so maybe that doesn't apply. Can you give us a clearer picture of what your library does for consumers?

Comment: @Greg - Yes, so maybe your `IProvideHeadersNamespace` interface has a method called something like `IList<string> GetHeaders` or if it is rows of header names, maybe `IList<IList<string>>` and so they pass whatever object implements that into your initialization function and your init function does whatever it needs to do to initialize your headers. Since they are the ones consuming your library, it seems cleaner to me to have an init function that requires them to provide you with the necessary data.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Rather than write code to parse a file, you would pass a configuration and the method for the parse you want to do, and it will return your object or objects mapped.

Comment: @Greg Sounds like if they want to do something related to parsing instances of ClassFoo, they can tell you about it then. I don't know what the configuration is or what "method for the parse" means or what "mapped" means in this case; do any of them affect anything?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why there's any need for the library to predict in advance what classes it might be asked to work with.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I won't know what models or entity will be passed.

Comment: @Greg OK, when these "models or entity" *are* passed, will you know about it then? Your deserialization (at least I think it's deserialization) has a requirement that in my (admittedly finite) experience is unprecedented. Why are your requirements different?

Comment: @EdPlunkett When they pass their header and model, yes.

Comment: @Greg So there's some information that you need, which can't be passed by the caller who passes you the header and model --  but which you can gather by enumerating all the classes in somebody's namespace. What information is that? Or is it that the *time* at which you have the information is critical? I suspect that this may be an X Y problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett My library would handle the parsing, but for the library to handle all variations, I would need some criteria to specify or handle the mapping portion correctly.  The model, not a problem since I can use generics.  The internal header structure of the file, so I can correctly manipulate to the model passed.  Due to the variation, nothing concrete to anchor to.

Comment: @Greg Well, I know the feeling of having nothing concrete to anchor to. Good luck.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you, the idea pstrjds has is interesting and might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Assembly.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx) does just that, loads a new assembly (roughly speaking, a DLL or EXE). If you just want to look for classes within the current assembly, use [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the currently executing `Assembly` object, and then call [`GetTypes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes(v=vs.110).aspx) on that.

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetCurrentlyExecutingAssembly();
var headers = assembly.GetTypes().Where(...);
```

MSDN has the following note regarding performance:

> For performance reasons, you should call this method only when you do not know at design time what assembly is currently executing. The recommended way to retrieve an Assembly object that represents the current assembly is to use the Type.Assembly property of a type found in the assembly, as the following example illustrates.

Unless you're running this code many times in a tight loop, there's no reason to be concerned with performance in my opinion. But if you want to follow MSDN's advice, you can replace `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` with `typeof(ThisClass).Assembly` where `ThisClass` is the name of the class containing the code. But `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` still works (and doesn't require coupling with the class name).